# Django Views. How can I change this code from functions based to class based

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm new to django and was doing most of the staff using function based views. Right now I need to change part of my code to class based and I've stacked for 2 days because can't find any information about implementation of categories using classes

So my current code in views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from .models import Category, Product


def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)
```

Here is my part of models related to categories:

```
class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('title',)
    verbose_name = 'категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'категории'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug        = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=49.99)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    featured    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I change my views to class based?

P.S I need to combine it with next ListView

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
template_name = 'products/list.html'
paginate_by = 6

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    return Product.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    cart_object, new_object = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
    context['cart'] = cart_object
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make it using classes but solved actual problem with next code:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
category = None
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.all()
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
cart_object, new_object = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)

context = {
    'category': category,
    'categories': categories,
    'products': products,
    'cart': cart_object
}
return render(request, 'products/list.html', context)
```

just added 2 necessary lines from listview to this:

```
cart_object, new_object = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
  context = {
    'category': category,
    'categories': categories,
    'products': products,
    'cart': cart_object
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can change your code like this :

```
from django.views import View

class ProductListView(View):
    def get(self, request, category_slug=None):
        category = None
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        if category_slug:
          category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
          products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)

        context = {
            'category': category,
            'categories': categories,
            'products': products
        }
        return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)
```

in urls.py, you must do like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('productlist/', ProductListView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to overwrite get and post methods; you should pick me specific ones.